# How to add references header to an email in actionmailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I have tried to add it using the headers as

```
headers "References" => "<message_id>"
```

But it is not found in the generated email. Moreover i have tried to add the In-Reply-To header and it dosen't show up either. I am using rails 2.3.8.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def notification(user)
    recipients    user.email
    from          "notifications@example.com"
    headers       {"References" => "<message_id>"}
    # code ...
  end
end
```

Check the documentation [here in guides for Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/action_mailer_basics.html#complete-list-of-action-mailer-user-settable-attributes) for the syntax how to specify the headers.

Comment: I have tried this. But it dosen't seem to work. No references header yet.

Comment: i have gone through the article mentioned but the after_action never gets triggered. Is there any method like enforce_message_id for references?

Comment: Once can you try setting the header `before_action` as described in [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-callbacks).

Comment: Are these callbacks available for my version of rails??

Comment: Sorry, those callbacks are not available in your version. and i didnt noticed your rails version, thats why i gave that link. And now i updated the post with your rails version, once check.

Comment: I have tried this and for some reason, the references alone is not being set in the headers. I tried setting mime-version and others like content-type which is successful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to set the references header:

```rb
def notification(user)

  headers['references'] = "message-id-example"

  mail(
    to: user.email,
    from: "email@email.com"
  )
end
```

For further info [check the documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#method-i-headers)